# Getting public void method variables into a private method?

Tags: java

For a project I am doing I am required to structure my code this way. However, the return statement on the calcMonthlyStatement returns a NaN(not a number) value. I'm assuming this is because I am dividing 0 by 0 in my monthlyPayment equation. I'm not sure how to get the variables **and their values** from my public void methods into my private one.

```
    import java.text.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.Math.*;
    public class Mortgage{
        private Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        private double principal;
        private double monthlyInt;
        private double numOfMonths; 
        private double monthlyPayment;
        private double totalPayment;
        Random rand = new Random();
        private int rng = rand.nextInt(9900) + 100;

    public void storeLoanAmount(double loanAmt){
        principal = loanAmt;
    }

    public void storeTerm(double term){
        numOfMonths = term;
    }


    public void storeInterestRate(double intRte){
        monthlyInt = intRte;
    }

    private double calcMonthlyPayment(){
        monthlyPayment = principal*((monthlyInt*(Math.pow((1+monthlyInt),numOfMonths)))/((Math.pow(1+monthlyInt,numOfMonths))-1));
        return monthlyPayment;
    }
    public String toString(){
         Mortgage call = new Mortgage();
         double mPayment = call.calcMonthlyPayment(); 
         String stats = ("Account number: " + rng +"\nThe monthly payment is $" + mPayment);
         return stats;
    }


//my main class from a seperate .java file

    public class MortgageEF{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Mortgage mort = new Mortgage();
    double principle = 100000;
    double numOfMonths = (15*12);
    double monthlyInt = ((5.5)/12);

    mort.storeLoanAmount(principle);
    mort.storeTerm(numOfMonths);
    mort.storeInterestRate(monthlyInt);

    System.out.print(mort.toString());
}

}
```

Comment: First, you should probably start your mutator methods with `set`; e.g. `setInterestRate`. `Principle` should probably be `principle`. Finally, have you tried setting any breakpoints? Alternatively, have you tried adding debugging statements?

Comment: you're using `Math.pow((1+monthlyInt),numOfMonths)` twice in the calc. Calculate it once and store it as a local var in `calcMonthlyPayment()`. Also, what values are you using `monthlyInt` and `numOfMonths`?

Comment: try checking values of `monthlyInt` , `numOfMonths` inside `calcMonthlypayment`

Comment: `double x =  Math.pow((1+monthlyInt), numOfMonths);`                `double d = Principle * ( (monthlyInt*x)/(x-1) );`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If we're going to recommend changing variable names, we may as well spell them correctly.  It should be `principal`.

Comment: @ajb Fair enough! It just looks like a class name in caps.

Comment: Alright I learned to spell, and also checked the values inside calcMonthlyPayment with print statements. they all print 0.0 at the moment. Inside the mutator methods the values all come out normally though. Also if I give the variables values inside the calcMonthlyPayment method (ex. principal = 6;, etc) then the output comes out normal

Comment: Is this actually Java? You didn't declare the type of `monthlyPayment`, so it shouldn't compile. Are `principal`, `numOfMonths`, and `monthlyInt` members of the class?

Comment: I don't think dividing 0 by 0 is the problem here, since the division is computing `p/(p-1)` for some `p` and it's impossible for both sides to be 0.  On the other hand, if the first argument to `Math.pow` is negative, it might lead to `NaN`.

Comment: @user3524921 If you say they are `0.0` at that moment, then I would expect that you have not set them to anything yet... show us your code where you are testing your class.

Comment: @2rs2ts Division-by-zero for floats results in an infinite result in Java, not an exception.

Comment: @ajb TIL. I've never encountered that in my five years of working with Java...

Comment: Are you using wrapper types? Please post the rest of this class, and the test harness. We're shooting in the dark.

Comment: We need to see all of the code.

Comment: OK, if all the variables are 0, you get a `NaN` because: `Math.pow(1,0)` is 1; you end up computing 1 / (1 - 1) which will be infinite; and then since `principal` is 0, it computes `0 * Infinity` which is `NaN` because it's an indeterminate form.

Comment: This is the full code with a few unused variables that I've yet to use.       The main method is required to be in another class and is only used to provide the values for loanAmt, term and intRte

Comment: @user3524921 I asked you for "your code where you are testing your class." That'd be the `main` method. Please post it.

Comment: I may have misread where `monthlyInt` was in the expression, so maybe it is a 0/0 case.

Comment: Added the main method. Sorry i misunderstood you. also added the method back that was originally printing the NaN error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're working with the wrong object.

```
public String toString(){
     Mortgage call = new Mortgage();
     double mPayment = call.calcMonthlyPayment(); 
     String stats = ("Account number: " + rng +"\nThe monthly payment is $" + mPayment);
     return stats;
}
```

The code in `main` creates a new `Mortgage`, and makes method calls that set up the fields.  But in the above code, instead of using the fields from this object, you're creating a *new* `Mortgage` object, which will then have 0's in all the fields; then you call `calcMonthlyPayment` on that new object, which returns `NaN` because it will use the fields in `call`, which are still 0, instead of the fields in `this` object, whose fields have the correct data.

There's no reason for `toString` to create a new object:

```
     //Mortgage call = new Mortgage();
     double mPayment = calcMonthlyPayment();
```